# Convert JooQ field to unqualified version while retaining type

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have a generated field named `table_name.field_name` that I can access using the `TABLE_NAME.FIELD_NAME` variable generated by JooQ. Let's say that `TABLE_NAME.FIELD_NAME` is a `Field<Integer>`.

I would like to obtain the unqualified version of that field, namely `field_name` as a `Field<Integer>`. I have found the following method which seems way too verbose to me:

```
DSL.field(TABLE_NAME.FIELD_NAME.getQualifiedName(), TABLE_NAME.FIELD_NAME.getType());
```

I had hoped there would be a way that would not be so verbose, something like:

```
TABLE_NAME.FIELD_NAME.uq();
```

Am I missing something that I could use for this usecase?

Comment: There's no such utility. But maybe there's a good enough solution to your actual problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a utility method for such operations:

```
private <T> Field<T> relField(Field<T> field) {
    return DSL.field(field.getUnqualifiedName(), field.getType());
}
```

This works good enough for my usecase. It would be nice to have official support for this though.